# Segmentation Fault with trap "kill 0" from subshell in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a little script that builds multiple Dockerfiles in parallel, however if I ever want to cancel the script I want to also kill the child processes. Doing so results in a `segmentation fault`, not sure why.

To clarify I'm killing the script with `^C`

```
trap "kill 0" SIGINT SIGTERM
DIRS=$( find . -name "Dockerfile" -printf "%h\n" )
for file in $DIRS; do  
    (   
        # testing script
        while :
        do
                echo "$file"
                sleep 1
        done
    ) & 
done
wait
```

Comment: What causes a segmentation fault? If it's `bash` itself you've found a bug in `bash`.

Comment: You have an infinite loop there.

Comment: I just get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` on my command line.

Comment: @Barmar the infinite loop is intended I'm just testing that the sub processes get killed

Comment: How many files is it finding? You may just be creating too many background processes.

Comment: @Barmar it only finds two

Comment: Do you even need the `find` to reproduce this? It could just be `DIRS="1 2"`, right?

Comment: @Barmar correct if you make your substitution the error still occurs

Comment: What version of `bash` are you running?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with bash 3.2.57 or 4.2.37

Comment: I'm on GNU bash 4.3.48, if i change `trap "kill 0"` to `trap "exit 0"` I no longer get the problem

Comment: I can reproduce this with bash 4.3.30

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Yeah i failed to copy that into the question but it's in the script

Comment: BTW, not related to the question, but this isn't a reliable way to store a list of UNIX paths in a variable. Any character that's allowed in a C string is also allowed in a path, so it's *completely impossible* to store a list of arbitrary filenames in a string; an array should be used instead. (Populating that array also needs to be done carefully to avoid bugs with file or directory names that contain newlines; an ideal approach will use `while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do array+=( "$name" ); done < <(find ... -print0)` or such).

Comment: I can replicate this with just `trap "kill 0" SIGINT SIGTERM; while :; do :; done`. If I put an `echo 'trap'` in the trap statement it looks like the trap statement is calling itself. This doesn't happen if the trap is only for one of `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple script:

```
trap "kill 0" SIGTERM
kill 0
```

will result in segmentation fault.
Why?
[kill](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/kill) command sends SIGTERM to the process. Our process on receiving SIGTERM executes signal handler for this signal, which is `kill 0`. This sends SIGTERM to the process again and executes the signal handler again. The process is stuck until [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), which results in segmentation fault.
Running such script with `bash -x` or with `set -x` results in smth like:

```
+ trap 'kill 0' SIGTERM
+ kill 0
++ kill 0
+++ kill 0
++++ kill 0
+++++ kill 0
...
+++++ ... so on ... ++++ kill 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Probably you meant `trap "exit 0" SIGTERM`.