# Best way to stop a bash script by ending processes

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to setup a startup script where I can send "start" and "stop" commands to the processes that the script has started.

What I came up with kills the process(es) alright, but I think I will get in trouble for larger processes, and I also think there might be a better way of doing this:

```
pingcheck()
{
    ping -c2 "$1" &>/dev/null
    return "$?"
}

start()
{
    while :
    do
        if ! pingcheck "$our_ip"; then
            echo "$our_ip NOT online, WANTEDID >> $WANTEDID"
        else
            echo "$our_ip IS online, WANTEDID >> $WANTEDID"
        fi
    done 
}

stop()
{
    #Find the start process's id
    WANTEDID=$(ps aux | grep '[n]etworking.sh start' | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1)
    #Kill it in a new processgroup
    setsid kill -9 "$WANTEDID"
    exit 0

}
trap "stop" SIGINT SIGTERM

case "$1" in
    start | stop ) "$1" ;;
esac

bash networking.sh start
192.168.20.5 IS online, WANTEDID >>
192.168.20.5 IS online, WANTEDID >>
192.168.20.5 IS online, WANTEDID >>
192.168.20.5 IS online, WANTEDID >>
192.168.20.5 IS online, WANTEDID >>
bash networking.sh stop
Killed
```

I would be grateful for any advice on how to write this better.

When I use SIGTERM, instead of -9 I get this in the screen and bash crashes (On ubuntu:

`++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ WANTEDID=26581
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ setsid kill -SIGTERM 26581
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ stop
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ps aux
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ awk '{print $2}'
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ grep '[n]etworking.sh start'
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ head -n 1
^C+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ WANTEDID=
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ setsid kill -SIGTERM ''
kill: failed to parse argument: ''
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ exit 0`

Comment: Why `kill -9`? Would a simple SIGTERM not be enough and cleaner?

Comment: The biggest problem is using `kill -9`, which will unconditionally murder the process. A gentler signal would be much more appreciated, so that the process can put its affairs in order before death.

Comment: Humans dont get to put their affairs in order, so, why should processes get the chance? :-)

Comment: Why this script kills itself after getting SIGINT killed? Is there any reason to run `setsid` ? If you remove the `trap` then you get expected behaviour? Do you want to run one process per script or multiple? How many? Will they run in background or as here as the process?

Comment: There is `start-stop-daemon` in Debian for exactly doing this. Or use systemd nowadays.

Comment: Better use `pgrep` or directly `pkill` than your `ps+grep+awk+head` pipeline

Comment: Right, use systemd for that. `systemd-run --user --name=myping /usr/bin/ping -c10 www.google.pl` . Then you can `systemctl --user status myping` and browse logs with `journalctl --user -u myping`

Comment: What about kill -STOP ? it will just stop the process instead of kill it definitely...

Comment: @KamilCuk after removing the trap and removing setsid, I got the expected behaviour with just `kill -SIGTERM <PID>` .

Comment: @aaron how do I use pgrep or pkill in this situation?

Comment: You can just `WANTEDID=$$`, you are quering for the pid of the current process.  And killing yourself inside a trap handler is just an endless loop (you kill the process, the trap handler gets executed, which kills the process, which executes trap handler and so on). In this case just `-9` signal is not handled, so the default handler is executed which just kills the current process. You can just remove the `trap` register and get same behavior.

Comment: I noticed that, yes. I also tried `WANTEDID=$$` but because I was running `bash scriptname.sh start` and `bash scriptname.sh stop` in different shells, I got a different value for `$WANTEDID` each time.

Comment: Each time you execute a process you will (should ;) ) get a different process id. Running `kill -SIGTERM` from a signal handler will result in endless killing-signal handler loop, just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453470/segmentation-fault-with-trap-kill-0-from-subshell-in-bash).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. So is `WANTEDID=$(pgrep -f "$0 start") && kill -SIGTERM "$WANTEDID" ` good enough?

Comment: `pkill -nf "$0 start"` should work nicely. `-n` to only kill the newest created process (I suppose equivalent to your `head -1`). That will send SIGTERM by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the stellar advice I got here (@Aaron, @Kamil Cuk), the script now looks like this:

```
pingcheck()
{
    ping -c2 "$1" &>/dev/null
    return "$?"
}

start()
{
    while :
    do
        if ! pingcheck "$our_ip"; then
            ...do something...
            sleep 10s
        fi
    done 
}

stop()
{
    pkill -nf "$0 start"
    exit 0
}

case "$1" in
    start | stop ) "$1" ;;
esac
```

And it works fine.
Thanks again everyone! I deeply appreciate all the help.